# Hide keyboard on ios titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

On my titanium app i have a form with many fields (textfield etc...), when i focus on textfield it shows the ios keyboard and i want to hide it when i click somewhere on the window :

```
<Alloy>
  <Window id="home" >
    <View id="form">
      <Require type="view" id="myViewForm" src="form/etape_1" />
    </View>
  </Window>
</Alloy>
```

inside myViewForm :

```
<Alloy>
    <View>
      <TextField id="name" hintText="name"/>
      <TextField id="telephone" hintText="Téléphone"/>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

Note : As you see i have a textfield with id "telephone" that will show only numbers.

on my controller home file :

```
/*-----------------------------------------
|   |   EVENT LISTENER CLICK ON WINDOW
-------------------------------------------*/
$.home.addEventListener("click", hideSoftKeyboard);
/*-----------------------------------------
|   |   HIDE KEYBOARD 
-------------------------------------------*/
function hideSoftKeyboard(e){
    if(Ti.Platform.osname === 'android'){
         Ti.UI.Android.hideSoftKeyboard();
    } else {
        $.home.textField.blur();
    }
}
```

On android it works well, but on Ios i have following error :

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      column = 103;
[ERROR] :      line = 12;
[ERROR] :      message = "undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.home.textField.blur')";
[ERROR] :      stack = hideSoftKeyboard;
[ERROR] :  }
```

Someone could help me please ? thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code for you:

***index.js***

```
$.home.addEventListener("click", hideSoftKeyboard);

$.home.open();

function hideSoftKeyboard(e){
    if(OS_ANDROID){
         Ti.UI.Android.hideSoftKeyboard();
    } else {
        $.myViewForm.name.blur();
        $.myViewForm.telephone.blur();
    }
}
```

- But also remember that if you do not set
  `bubbleParent="false"` on text-fields, then your click event on window will be fired up as soon as you click on text-field.
- So be careful about using click event on whole window.
- If your purpose of using click event on window is just to hide keyboard on iOS using phone layout keyboard, then I will suggest you to look this property [TextField keyboardToolbar](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField-property-keyboardToolbar) which will serve your purpose well.

Here is the complete cross-platform code to hide telephone keyboards.

***index.js***

```
$.home.open();
```

***myViewForm.xml***

```
<Alloy>
    <View layout='vertical'>
        <TextField id="MOBILE_FIELD" class="phone fields" platform="android" />

        <TextField id="MOBILE_FIELD" class="phone fields" platform="ios">
            <KeyboardToolbar>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Items>
                        <FlexSpace />
                        <Button title="DONE" onClick="hideKeyboard" />      
                    </Items>
                </Toolbar>
            </KeyboardToolbar>
        </TextField>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

***myViewForm.tss***

```
// to accept only phone numbers, with + sign also..
".phone[platform=ios]" : {
    keyboardType : Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_TYPE_NUMBER_PAD,
}

".phone[platform=android]" : {
    inputType : [Ti.UI.INPUT_TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER]
}


".fields" : {
    top : 30
    width : '80%',
    height : 50,
    borderColor : 'black',
    borderWidth : 2
}
```

***myViewForm.js***

```
function hideKeyboard() {
    $.MOBILE_FIELD.blur();
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much, your response and examples are very clear, so i have to repeat <KeyboardToolbar> fore each field i need on my form?

Answer (score -2):

Try with

```
$.myViewForm('name').blur();
$.myViewForm('telephone').blur();
```

in place of `$.home.textField.blur();`

`$.myViewForm('name')` will get the view with id `name` which will be your textfield, and then you can call `blur()` method on that.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: We cannot access the id of elements this way, but its rather slightly different.

It should be like this : $.myViewForm.name.blur();
  $.myViewForm.telephone.blur();

Comment: Hello, all your responses are very useful for me, and thank for your times guys, so all of you mean that if i have many fields on my form i have to do it manually ?

Comment: @user44321 yes you have to do it manually for iOS. if you find any answer helpful mark it as accepted and do upvote, so it will be helpful for other users too. :)